# How to pass argument in Visual Studio 2010 C++ for Windows 8 ?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-8, argument-passing

Following code works in Windows XP and Windows 7, but not in Windows 8. 
I can get the file path and open in XP and 7. But when I try to open in windows 8 it doesn't work. Why ? any idea ?  Thanks.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if (argc == 2)
  {
    if(OpenFile(argv[1], false))
        cout<<"\nFile has been opened successfully."<<endl;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: are you using this [OpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365430(v=VS.85).aspx) - doesn't seem to mesh argument-wise.  Also, what's not working - you don't get the file path in argv[1] or you do and the file doesn't open?

Comment: No I am not using this OpenFile, I am using c openfile File* fopen(), Actually I have developed an application which take an argument and open the file. after compiling I got an exe file. that Exe works perfect in XP and 7, but Exe doesn't work on windows 8. Applicatin opens without file.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.. The issue was with FLTK argument pass. I have ignored it and created a simple argument as I mention above at beginning of the main function.